# Ways of loading Image-Data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

I want to develop classification networks that are able to train on my own image datasets. I think, that I got the network creation part, however, I'm having a hard time getting my image data imported.
I want a general model for different datasets since I intend to reuse the image loading methods. Therefore I want it to be structured in folders like this:

- image_dir

  - Label_1  --> Images Reside within these
  - Label_2  --> Images Reside within these
  - ...

Now it seems like there are many options for this.

1. Using `Preloaded Data` (Not applicable since I want this to be generalizable also for large datasets)
2. Load the images themselves as `numpy arrays` using a `filename_queue` (As I see it, this should be slower throughout training than using `TFRecords` since I would need to access the individual images multiple times)
3. `TFRecords` (I was able to convert into this format using [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py), however, I'm not sure how to get them going for training)
4. Maybe more?

So I basically have two questions:

1. Which way of loading image data is the preferred one for which use case? (general question for everyone who stumbles across this problem)
2. Is `TFRecords` the right way for my problem, and if yes, is there a generalizable way to load the `TFRecord` File and get the data ready for training?

Comment: for reading `TFRecod` files, check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py).

Comment: Looking at a few vision models, it seems like they all use TFRecord (e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/ed65b6324b5c554094eca2c0e3d7d2686af7a9f5/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md).

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "is there a generalizable way to load the TFRecord". The structure that you are proposing is used by ImageNet here is an example of how it is processed: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py

Comment: Thank you, I think this already answers most of my questions. Then I just need to get my code working which is another topic. What I see from your posts is, that TFRecords is the right way to go, so I'll stick with it.